# Jquery AutoCompleate Ajax ASP.NET - Nothing happens

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I cant get my Jquery UI autocompleate to work. 
Edit: I parse my list to json, and get json when debugging, but my autocopleate is nor responding, nothing comes up under the textbox and no errormessage

I have .NET 4.5

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $(".tags").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../SearchService/Search.ashx?term=" + request.term,
                        data: {},
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('error');
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log('YES');
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.dataFromServer
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        });
 </script>
```

Service (edit serialized json)

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string searchstring = context.Request.QueryString["term"]!= null ? context.Request.QueryString["term"] : string.Empty;
        //string searchstring = "Ögon";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            context.Response.Write(GetJSON(ProductSearch(searchstring)));
        }


    }

    public List<String> ProductSearch(string searchstring)
    {
        LinqtoDBDataContext db = new LinqtoDBDataContext();

        var searchresult = db.SearchCatalog(searchstring);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in searchresult)
        {
            list.Add(item.SearchOut);
        }


        return list;


    }

    public static string GetJSON(object obj)
    {
        var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var sbJsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        oSerializer.Serialize(obj, sbJsonResults);
        return sbJsonResults.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you missed success function..?

```
  success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.dataFromServer
                    }
                }))
            },
```

Comment: I put this in and now it works thanks

success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }